# Enabling remote debug in Eclipse by connecting to remote server

Tags: eclipse, debugging

In my project, application is running on remote server. I need to debug it locally in Eclipse. How can I debug it in Eclipse? Is it possible or not? Currently I'm deploying a war file in server and seeing changes but it is taking so much time.

Comment: What application server are you using? (Tomcat, Glassfish..)

Comment: tomcat server is used